# How to visualize or format a diff / patch file?

Tags: formatting, diff, visualization, patch

I have a patch file (unified diff), like the output from `svn diff`, `git diff`, or `diff -u ...`. I want to review it, but the unified diff format - especially with many files & changes - is hard on my eyes.

How can I get a nicely-formatted diff view from the patch file? I don't have the files themselves, only the diff, so I can't use all the regular diff tools.

So far my 2 best tactics are:

1. Load the diff in gvim and get some syntax highlighting
2. Paste the diff into a Trac wiki in a `#!diff`-formatted section and click "preview" - this creates an awesome diff view:

```
{{{
#!diff
<unified diff here>
}}}
```

Are there desktop tools that can do this? Is there a way to persuade kdiff3 / diffmerge / p4merge / etc. to visualize the patch file? Something that replicates Trac's visualization would be great as well.

EDIT: bonus points for Windows support as well, preferably with an installer or a pain-free installation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using kompare - http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/. It should do the job.

EDIT: Also, check out the list of file comparison tools here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools - have a look at the column "Patch preview" in one of the tables.

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks! As a Windows user I'd prefer a standalone download though :(

Comment: There's supposed to be a standalone installer here: <https://kde.org/applications/development/org.kde.kompare>, but when I checked this morning, there's a ReferenceError coming up when you try to use it :(

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [idiff](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/idiff)

Comment: Thanks, cool script! I currently get the same effect from piping into VIM (cross-platform too, good for Windows), except the ability to keep piping.

Answer (score 5):

Not a Windows solution, but if you're on Mac OS X, PatchViewer (http://appledeveloper.com.au/products/patchviewer/) will do what you're after.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of PatchViewer.)

Comment: [spoke too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895005/tortoisesvn-good-patch-file-viewer/14846390#comment80055012_14846390) :^D