# Git format-patch viewer?

Tags: git

Somebody is sending me patches generated by "git format-patch".

Is there a gui (on linux) that can open these .patch files?

I've tried many diff gui but all they do is compare two existing files/folders. None can display the patch, except kompare which spits a "The diff is malformed. Some lines could not be parsed and will not be displayed in the diff view." everytime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're pretty easy to read, but if you want to see the entire context of the file, the best way is to apply them with `git-am`:

```
git am foo.patch
git difftool ORIG_HEAD
```

If you like it, it's already committed.  If not:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: I guess that's the reason why no guy is doing what I'm asking. Since git is so powerful, doing everything in git directly is possible.

Comment: I think I'll do this: 1) create a branch, 2) apply all patches, 3) review with any gui, 4) merge the branch or cherry-pick some commits.

Comment: I'd like to add that to review difference between commits, "git-meld" from https://github.com/wmanley/git-meld is amazing. So: 1) Branch 2) apply patches 3) git meld commit1..commit2

Comment: as a 2 cents, personally I would do as above but use git diff all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial

Answer (score 57):

I've made a tool to view diff side-by-side:
http://megatops.github.io/PatchViewer/

Screenshot:
[image]

Now it was updated to v0.4 to support file list.

Source code: https://github.com/megatops/PatchViewer

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? I find it a useful tool!

Comment: Nice tool! Downloadable as a single .html file, which according to [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) doesn't attempt to load any external scripts. Thanks!

Comment: I see you have created 2 accounts. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts if you wish to merge them (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238572/ding-zhaojie, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238814/ding-zhaojie)

Comment: This should be the top answer for this question.
#1 it works
#2 simple install (download 1 file)
#3 minimal deps (no external that I can tell)
#4 is fast
#5 looks good too!

Comment: Outstanding tool. Simply download the [html file above](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/megatops/PatchViewer/master/PatchViewer.html), open it in your browser, this allows you to open the patch files and it shows the diff files before and after side by side, like the picture shows. Superb, should be built into git.

Comment: Just for fun, [I hacked into a fiddle quickly](https://jsfiddle.net/vx968eyg/). I'm not sure if the app.box.com url used to run it, but it looks like it's just dumping the script now.

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution:

```
cat patch | colordiff | less -RS
```

Further reading: [http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405204310/http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/) (archived copy)

Comment: requires colordiff which you may have to install (not installed on my Mac)

Answer (score 4):

The `.diff` and `.patch` files that git generates are just plain-text diff files.

Most text editors on linux should be able to open and syntax-highlight the diff files. Emacs and vim should be able to view them without any problem, as should gedit, kate, or pretty much any other syntax-highlighting text editor.

If you don't need syntax highlighting, `less`, `cat`, or anything else that displays plain text should also show you the changes.

Answer (score -1):

[Git Cola](https://git-cola.github.io/) includes an "Apply Patches" dialog that can be launched from the Actions menu, or via the `git cola am` sub-command.  You can open patches in this dialog and display the contents with diff syntax highlighting.

This feature is available in `master` by cloning the repo and will be in the upcoming `v3.3` release.

Answer (score -3):

They are supposed to be human-readable text. Open them in a text editor.

Edit: or apply the patch on a branch, then you can use whatever tool you normally use to compare branches.

Edit 2: oh you already thought of that, never mind.

Comment: Of course, but a gui is always nice to have. For example, a smart one could show you that on one extra long line which character changed. Meld will show you the two lines side by side and highlight the changed character. Looking at the patch in a text editor won't reveal easily this small change.

Comment: @big_gie wait 'til you learn about `git diff --word-diff`!